# jQuery Validate make submit in specified div

Tags: jquery, html, validation, submit

On my **index.php** page, form action attribute is *'target.php'*. I use jQuery Valdiate to validate the form.

```
<form action="target.php" method="post" class="contact-validate">
    <div>
        <div id="sent"></div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Przedstaw się" name="name" id="name" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Miejscowość" name="city" id="city" />
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Send form *</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is that after correct validation, action form is performed as other page, but i need this action can be execute in #sent div.

Here the jQuery code

```
<script>
jQuery('.contact-validate').validate({
    rules: {
        "name": {
            required: true
        },
        "city": {
            required: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        form.submit();
    }
});
</script>
```

I don't know what i need to add in 'submitHandler'

Comment: ... to add Ajax form submitting, for example.

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: So jquery Validate don't have own ability to do this? I need use ajax?

Comment: @X9DESIGN This is what is written in  [documenation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#submithandler).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `form.submit()` if you want to the page remaining after submitting the form. Instead you can use `ajaxSubmit()` function of jquery like this,

**HTML**

```
<form action="target.php" id="theform" method="post" class="contact-validate">
    <div>
        <div id="sent"></div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Przedstaw się" name="name" id="name" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Miejscowość" name="city" id="city" />
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Send form *</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
jQuery('.contact-validate').validate({
    rules: {
        "name": {
            required: true
        },
        "city": {
            required: true
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $("#theform").ajaxSubmit({url: 'target.php', type: 'post'});
        $("#theform").submit(function(e){ // I think you need to prevent the actual (normal without ajax) form submitting.
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: The `submitHandler` option of `$.validate` will prevent the submit if you `return false`, so you can do that instead of adding another `submit` event handler to the form.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent a form from submission, you can use either

```
//(jQuery) prevent default functionality of the button
e.preventDefault();
```

or

```
//(javascript) return from the method so it does not submit.
return false;
```

I m not pretty sure about the later one. let me know once you try.

Cheers!!